# Un-"Fit" for airbag diagnosis

Tags: honda, supplemental-restraint-system, fit

My daughter has a 2009 Honda Fit Sport. When we bought the car about a year ago, I noticed one thing and didn't notice another concerning the airbags. During POST at first startup, the airbag light is supposed to come on, stay on for a few seconds, then go out. This tells the driver the system is working correctly. When we first bought the car, I didn't realize the light wasn't coming on at all. I did, however, plug my scanner into the OBDII port and read the SRS system, which shows no codes are present. Since it shows no codes are present, I know it is at least communicating with the SRS system (you can see the scanner saying it is starting comms with the SRS module). Since there is no light present, this still tells me there's *something* going on with the system. This could be as simple as the light being covered with a piece of black electrical tape or possibly the LED which illuminates it has gone out ... I don't know as of yet. The second thing which is confusing is, the passenger side airbag light (which should illuminate when there's nobody in the seat showing that airbag as inoperable) is blinking while the car is turned on.

The scanner is picking up no codes. I've looked on the internet to see what could be the issue with the blinking passenger side airbag light, but nothing even close to conclusive.

My question is, **how would I go about diagnosing what is going on?**

### UPDATES

I took the dash apart under the suspicion of unscrupulous selling practices. My hunch was right: someone put black electrical tape over the main airbag, side airbag, and TPMS dash lights. All three now show illuminated. The side airbag light blinks in time with the passenger airbag light on the dash (under the radio). This modifies my question to:

**How can the reader tell me there's nothing wrong (no codes) yet the airbag light is on?** What may be going on here? Without proper diagnostics connection, how can I tell what's going on with the SRS?

Comment: Does the passenger side have a switch - perhaps in the glove box, to turn off the passenger side? some cars do... that may influence the passenger side light operation... As for the dash - there have been some who disable the light so it passes inspection...

Comment: @SolarMike - The Fit uses a seat sensor. Most likely the "80-lb" version. There has to be over 80-lbs of weight in the seat for the airbag to be activated. It shouldn't blink, though. It should stay solid when there's nobody in the seat. And it should be unlit when there's someone there, which it doesn't do.

Comment: Just asking as mine has a switch in the glove box AND a seat sensor... I have put a bag on the seat and it notices...

Comment: @SolarMike - I'll double check, but I've not seen anything like that on the Fit. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Could also be a seat belt issue, not sure if those codes are stored in the bcm or not.

Comment: @Moab - It did pop for the seat belt in my '03 Civic, so would *assume* it would for the Fit as well. I've found a few things which need to get fixed. I don't know if there is a manual process for clearing the airbag light. I've seen YouTube videos of there being a yellow plug under the dash of other Honda vehicles which you use a jumper to help you clear the light, but I don't know how much that'd help me. I looked for the plug, but didn't find one on the Fit. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 if there is a seat belt malfunction it will trigger an air bag light, but I think that is a different computer that sets the code and turns on the light.. You might need a more advanced code reader to pull the code and reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is, that when there is an accident with airbag deployment, the airbag computer has a "flag" (for lack of a better word) in it which has to be reset. Until you get it reset, it's basically a dead system even if you replace the deployed airbags. To fix the issue, there are companies which will provide a service to reset the codes. I found these are relatively cheap in comparison to purchasing a new computer and getting it "attuned" to your vehicle (with the need to set the VIN within the computer and whatever else they do). To get one new or out of a wrecking yard will cost you (here in the States) ~$1,000 at the time of this post, whereas to get the original computer reset only costs about $50 (plus shipping). A much more affordable endeavor.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Doesn't look that hard to do either.

Comment: @Ben - Hopefully that's all which is still wrong with it at this point. I replaced an airbag (pass side curtain) which was a PITB. Got it for a good price, though ;-)